# DocuSign C# SDK: Error calling ListStatusChanges: The operation has timed out

Tags: docusignapi

I am making a request for envelopes statuses. In my request options, I have opted to get the recipients as well. Here is my code for the request.

```
public List<Envelope> GetEnvelopes()
{
      AuthenticateTheClient();

      DateTime lastStatusChangedUtcDateTime = envelopeRepository.GetMostRecentStatusChangedUtcDateTime();
      DateTime fromUtcDate = docuSignSettings.SearchFromDate.ToUniversalTime();
      fromUtcDate = lastStatusChangedUtcDateTime.Date > fromUtcDate.Date ? lastStatusChangedUtcDateTime : fromUtcDate;
      var options = new ListStatusChangesOptions()
      {
            fromDate = $"{fromUtcDate:yyyy/MM/dd}",
            fromToStatus = docuSignSettings.FromToStatus,
            searchText = docuSignSettings.SearchText,
            status = docuSignSettings.Status,
            toDate = $"{docuSignSettings.SearchToDate:yyyy/MM/dd}",
            include = "recipients"
      };

      EnvelopesInformation envelopesInformation = envelopesApi.ListStatusChanges(account.AccountId, options);
      return envelopesInformation.Envelopes ?? new List<Envelope>();
}
```

The problem is when I run the code, I get the following error: "Error calling ListStatusChanges: The operation has timed out."

Stack Trace:

```
"   at DocuSign.eSign.Api.EnvelopesApi.ListStatusChangesWithHttpInfo(String accountId, ListStatusChangesOptions options)\r\n   at DocuSign.eSign.Api.EnvelopesApi.ListStatusChanges(String accountId, ListStatusChangesOptions options)\r\n   at DocuSignIntegrator.Service.DocuSignService.GetEnvelopes() in C:\\Repos\\DocuSign\\src\\DocuSignIntegrator.Service\\DocuSignService.cs:line 55\r\n   at DocuSignIntegrator.App.DocuSignApp.<Run>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\\Repos\\DocuSign\\src\\DocuSignIntegrator.App\\DocuSignApp.cs:line 34"
```

Thanks for your help and consideration.

Comment: what version of the SDK are you using? (Nuget package)?

Comment: Hi, I am using version 4.1.1

Comment: can you update "yyyy/MM/dd" in your code with actual dates?

Comment: Hi, those are format strings in C#. It just means the date will output as 2019/10/29. The actual date is in the variable fromUtcDate.

Comment: how many envelopes do you expect to get back? can you try to narrow it down and see if it works then?

Answer (score 0):

This API call may take a long time and may timeout as a result of too much data.
Note that this API call is going to retrieve all the envelops in the account for all users during the particular period of time. 
Please look in [this guide](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/envelopes/search) about the best way to search for envelopes which is 
reflected in the options you pass `ListStatusChanges` when you call from the SDK.